# Custom AutoMapper name/type convention for all mappings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper 6.0 in my ASP.NET MVC application for mapping between entities and view models. Entities are using **byte[8] Version** property, but view models are using **ulong Version** property. Because of different property types default mapping ignores that field and I'm ending up with default value for view model (that is 0).

Currently I'm calling below code after each _mapper.Map(entity,viewModel);

```
_mapper.Map(entity,viewModel);
viewModel.Version = System.BitConverter.ToUInt64(entity.Version.ToArray(), 0);
```

How can I configure AutoMapper during initialisation so second line won't be necessary?

I have hundreds of models so instead of creating custom maps with ForMember(cfg) configuration I would like to amend AutoMapper convention so above type of conversion happens by default for each map, eg:

```
public class MyCustomProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public MyCustomProfile()
    {
        CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        //use custom converter for this convetion: ulong vVersion = BitConverter.ToUInt64(eVersion.ToArray(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a type mapping with the ConvertUsing:

```
CreateMap<byte, ulong>().ConvertUsing(System.Convert.ToUInt64);
```

Edit, as requested:

```
CreateMap<byte[], ulong>().ConvertUsing(x=> BitConverter.ToUInt64(x, 0));
```

Comment: Almost perfect! Thank you! You've solved this riddle.
Can you please edit your answer with correct code for above example? CreateMap<byte[], ulong>().ConvertUsing(x=> BitConverter.ToUInt64(x, 0)); Thanks!